# Adding Buttons to Datagrid Cell WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create DataGrid control in WPF in which there are 4 buttons in last column. I need to change background color of each button for each row independently.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Progress">    
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>    
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Name="spBtnDG" Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Button Name="btnPhaseI" MouseEnter="btnPhaseI_MouseEnter"      Width="110" Height="8"  Content=""/>
       <Button Name="btnPhaseII" MouseEnter="btnPhaseII_MouseEnter"  Width="110" Height="8" Content="" />
       <Button Name="btnPhaseIII" MouseEnter="btnPhaseIII_MouseEnter"   Width="110" Height="8" Content="" />
       <Button Name="btnPhaseIV"  MouseEnter="btnPhaseIV_MouseEnter" Width="110" Height="8" Content="" />
      </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When i change background color for first button it will change background color for every first button in every row. I need to have ability to change it for each row separately. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your ItemsSource?

Comment: When are you going to request the color change? While the application is running or on load?

Comment: @user2858484 while application is running. In second usercontrol user will have ability to change progress. Look at screenshot please [https://pasteboard.co/IfQm0S5.png ] For example when he changes colors on first 3 button for preparation phase, first button in datagrid(datagrid is in first usercontrol) needs to change background color. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

In the function for the event MouseEnter you need to cast the property `Source` in the `MouseEventArgs` object to `Button` and store it as variable. Then you can change its Background.
Example:

```
private void btnPhaseI_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var btn = (Button)e.Source;
  btn.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
}
```